# Best practice to implement a custom splash screen with storyboard

Tags: ios5, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, uianimation

I have been designing a custom splash screen using the following approach:

- I have one splash creen controller that's been defined as a rootview controller in storyboard.
- The splash screen controller is taking care of making a screenshot of itself and a custom container controller i would like to segue to. When the screenshots have all been taken care of, I allow the user to segue to the container controller (by doing a custom modal segue).

I think there are 2 problems with this approach:

1. The splash screen controller is still in memory even when i don't need it anymore.
2. I am loading the view for the first controller contains within my custom container controller 2 times: one when i am making a screenshot of the container controller and an other one when i am presenting modally the containerview controller.

Would it possible using storyboard to present modally the splashscreen just before the view for the container controller has even loaded? Can i have a custom segue when the splashscreen is being dismissed?

Comment: What is the aim of this "splash screen"?

Comment: I want to preload a couple of views that usually take time to display

Comment: Can you specify what you're trying to display?

Comment: My custom container controller contains two view controllers. Each of them contain a grid view of images.

Comment: I am sorry i might have confused you: the part that takes time is not the display but loading the view for those controllers